# render bloom in eevee without cutting by silhouette

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I want to render image with postprocess effects but bloom cutted in final render in eevee

[image]

How can i solve that problem? may be i need activate/deactivate some option in render setting or same?

Answer (score 1):

That node tree in composer solve the problem
[image]